# noscript alternative in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, web-standards

In HTML I could do:

```
<noscript><link href="css/stylenojs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></noscript>
```

Is there some compliant way to do so in XHTML Transitional or Strict documents?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829671/is-it-wise-to-use-the-noscript-tag-for-tracking-visitors-who-have-javascript-dis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you give is invalid in HTML as well as XHTML. No current recommendation provides a way to include a stylesheet *unless* scripting is enabled.

In general, you should avoid `<noscript>`. Start with something that works, and then [build on it.](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build)

In this case, you could write your stylesheet for non-JS clients, then:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">document.body.className += ' js';</script>
```

… and include additional rule-sets specific to JS being enabled with:

```
body.js foo {
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
<link href="css/stylenojs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="nojscss" />
```

and

```
var nojscss = document.getElementById('nojscss');
nojscss.parentNode.removeChild(nojscss);
```

Comment: Actually what Richard has written is valid HTML5, as both no script and self closing tags are okay, but yes, even XHTML5 doesn't allow the <noscript>. This limitation means if you want to do certain things in an elegant *and* valid way you HAVE to execute JavaScript on page load (which also is not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

The current chosen answer is misleading.

`<noscript>` is [HTML valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript#specifications) as well as the example provided in the question.

[W3C says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element):

> The noscript element is only effective in the HTML syntax, it has no
>   effect in the XHTML syntax. This is because the way it works is by
>   essentially "turning off" the parser when scripts are enabled, so that
>   the contents of the element are treated as pure text and not as real
>   elements. XML does not define a mechanism by which to do this.

Now, the little [dirty secret](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/03/19/dive-into-xml.html) about XHTML is that browsers are not treating XHTML in XML unless the documented is served in `application/xhtml+xml` as the MIME type.

In case your page is served as proper `XHTML`, then a solution might be changing the `doctype` of the page to HTML5 and MIME type to `text/html`.