# XHTML document type does not allow element "style" in body

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I have a document using XHTML Transitional. In the body I use a `<noscript>` tag with a `<style type="text/css">`.

I know that `<style type="text/css">` is only allowed in the `<head>`, but still I need to have the CSS applied only if JavaScript isn't detected.

How can I solve this problem, while still passing XHTML validation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
  <noscript>
    <div id="section-featured-nojavascript" class="section">
      <style type="text/css">
        #featured, #section-portfolio { display:none; visibility:hidden }
      </style>
    </div>
  </noscript>
</body>
```

ERROR when validation using W3

```
document type does not allow element "style" here [XHTML 1.0 Transitional]
```

Comment: Isn´t `<noscript>` allowed in the `<head>`? :)

Comment: You could try the other way: Use this stylesheet by default and use JavaScript to make them visible.

Comment: Hi Stefan, sorry I forgot to write in my question the <noscript> is in the BODY, any idea how to solve it? thanks

Comment: @Stefan — No, it isn't (not in XHTML 1.0 Transitional at least).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902658/noscript-alternative-in-xhtml answered by @Quentin

Comment: Thanks Stefan your resource help me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to have a separate stylesheet. Use JS to add a `js` class to the `<body>` (or to remove a `no-js` class). Then use that as part of a descendent selector in your main stylesheet.

Comment: It is a pretty standard technique. I was using it in the 90s… years before modernizr came on the scene.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for your answer, but I'm not able to understand your point, could you add a short example or a link to some resource? many thanks!

Comment: `.js p { background: sky-blue-pink; }` & `document.body.className += ' js'`

Answer (score 0):

You could set

```
#featured, #section-portfolio { display:none; visibility:hidden }
```

by default in your css and "undo" it with javascript?

From w3schools:
The noscript tag is used to provide an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn’t support client-side scripting.

The noscript element can contain all the elements that you can find inside the body element of a normal HTML page.

The content inside the  element will only be displayed if scripts are not supported, or are disabled in the user’s browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the css file using javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>What ever</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripting_off.css"  id="client_side_scripting"/>
<script  type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('client_side_scripting').setAttribute('href','scripting_on.css');
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```