# Is it wise to use the noscript tag for tracking visitors who have javascript disabled, since noscript is deprecated?

Tags: html, analytics, noscript, matomo

Piwik (open source web analytics) uses javascript to track visitors. However, for visitors who have javascript disabled they suggest using the `<noscript>` tag:

> When a visitor has disabled JavaScript, or when JavaScript cannot be
>   used, you can use an image tracking link to track visitors. Generate
>   the link below and copy-paste the generated HTML in the page. If
>   you're using this as a fallback for JavaScript tracking, you can
>   surround it in `<noscript></noscript>` tags.

Using a `js` vs `no-js` class on the body isn't really an option, since that would not be able to prevent the image from loading. So the noscript tag seems like my only option, but will it work as expected since it is deprecated?

Comment: I noticed in the past that `<noscript>` elements are not handled very consistently across browsers. Some treated it as a block, some as inline; some browsers never showed the content at all, even if you switched Javascript off, etc. Can't really recommend it.

Comment: This question is especially relevant with XHTML5, where `<noscript>` tags are no longer supported; resulting in the image being loaded twice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitors that have JavaScript disabled means practically:

1. Screen readers for blind people - I don't see a reason they should download images
2. Some bored admin viewing page with text-mode browser - no images downloaded as well
3. Google BOT or some other bot crawling pages - they would do with the links what they want, for example ignore it
4. Scripts writing the page for offline usage, that would save the image or not, depending on the settings (in most cases not)

The only place where such image-tracking could have work are the HTML mail messages, but such images are normally blocked, or you could fall under spam filter.

Comment: Or someone using noscript. But I don't know how abundant they are. I know I've used it for a while.

Comment: Basically what my question is, is if it will work as expected. I know I'll pick up bots, screenreaders and the likes, but I'll take that for granted. I'm just interested in whether it will work as expected, and if there are any significant downsides.

Comment: @Samuel I think there are slighlty more of them then unicorns.

Comment: :) Really? Is that by experience, or could you point me to a source somewhere? Anyway, it's good news I guess.

Comment: I see that it's about 1% on average. Not much indeed. I'm still wondering how many unicorns there are though. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: If you consider modern day rhinoceros's still unicorns (as apposed to their ancestor the Siberian unicorn), then there are approx 27,000 unicorns currently in existence, which is a substantially smaller # than 1% of the population.  So @Samuel is partially correct, there are more but not substantially more.

I'm really...really bored.